# Why torch does train using mini-batches?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, torch, torchvision

I'm currently tring to understand how to train models via `pytorch`. And while this I saw a pretty interesting feature: passing to train data --- is a mini-batch. For ex.

There is a code fragment from official pytorch [web-site](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/transfer_learning_tutorial.html)

```py
...

data_dir = 'data/hymenoptera_data'
image_datasets = {x: datasets.ImageFolder(os.path.join(data_dir, x),
                                          data_transforms[x])
                  for x in ['train', 'val']}
dataloaders = {x: torch.utils.data.DataLoader(image_datasets[x], batch_size=4,
                                             shuffle=True, num_workers=4)
              for x in ['train', 'val']}

...
```

```py
...

for inputs, labels in dataloaders[phase]:
    inputs = inputs.to(device)
    labels = labels.to(device)

    optimizer.zero_grad()

    with torch.set_grad_enabled(phase == 'train'):
        outputs = model(inputs)
        _, preds = torch.max(outputs, 1)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)

...
```

According to this code, inputs that passing to model is a mini-batch.

I've tied to fiend some info about this, but unsuccessfully.

But I'm really curious, is it some kind of boost (parallel run, etc.) or neccussary thing. So, would you mind to help me figure it out and tell me, why there is a mini-batch passing to train function?

N.B. Will not refuse a link to the paper [smily :)].

Comment: You rarely train over the entire dataset (due to computational limits) thus you train over batches of the data instead

Comment: Then how does model learn to proceed one image to compute the predictions, while training on batches? How does it runs in general?

Comment: Using mini-batches allows for faster convergence. [This](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/16807/why-mini-batch-size-is-better-than-one-single-batch-with-all-training-data) may be helpful.

Comment: Besides mathematics and academic problems, inputting the entire dataset will need a huge memory that is normally not suitable for the image data type (in your example). For example, one image has a size of 224x224x3, a thousand images will have 1,505,28,000 pixels, not mention to the intermediate values that need to compute the gradient while training the model. A standard dataset normally has more than 50,000 samples.

Comment: Then why wouldn't we want to pass a signle image to the network, calculate the gradient and start again with next image? This way each iteration we just cacheing data for current image, not for whole dataset.
Isn't gradient memory over an iteration approximatly the same?
Why would we have to pass X images rather than 1?

Comment: Did you check the link in @BrokenBenchmark comment? I think the explanation is clear

Comment: Ok, I got the idea, why we use mini-batches.
But I dont get why you mention the example of `1,505,28,000 pixels`. It seems to be a bad point for batches, not for naive method. It confused me a bit. @CuCaRot

Comment: In your question, there are two different methods, use one sample per iteration or entire dataset per one-time training. People try to explain the first for you, I want to talk about the latter, in case you don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine it this way; say you want to learn the difference between a dog and a cat, and you have never seen them before.
The batches would be that we show you, say, 10 images of a dog and a cat at a time. You can, rather fast, learn the some of differences of cats and dogs after say 4x10 images (4 batches) but you'll of course be biased if e.g all the dogs you've been showed so far have been large dogs, thus you might classify all small dogs as cats. After enough batches you'll learn, and then unlearn, different features since you don't see them all at once, but the important thing is, you start learning something fast.

On the other hand, say we show you 100 images instead of 10. It will take much longer for you to look all the images through and compare them to each other, but you'll learn the differences in "one go" so to speak.

Either way; when you have processed those images (either as batches or the entire dataset), I can then show you one image, and you can tell me if it is a dog or a cat, even though you have learned from multiple images.